# Connecting to mysql database using php 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I'm trying to connect to a mysql database using php 5.3 but I can't seem to connect. I'm trying to debug this code:

```
<?php
    class DB_Connect {
        private $conn;

        // Connecting to database
        public function connect() {

            // Connecting to mysql database
            $this->conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database_name');
                // return database handler
                return $this->conn;
        }   
    }
?>
```

Basically what I want is code I can add to the file to help me debug it. Here is an example of what I have already tried to use although I now know this code is wrong:

```
            .....
            ......
            if ($this->conn->connect_error) {
            die('Connect Error (' . $this->conn->connect_errno . ') '
                        . $this->conn->connect_error);
            }else {
                echo('connected');
                // return database handler
                return $this->conn;
            }
            ....
            ....
```

Comment: Do you get an error when you try to connect?

Comment: That code seems like a correct part of error checking. The missing part is handling any exceptions that may be thrown from `new mysqli` .

Comment: Just a brief overview: I'm connecting an android app to a database but when it tries to call on the php files I get a connection error on the app. I know the problem is in my php code but i dont know which file (why I need the debug code). ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION: Not when I run this specific php file from the browser. I currently have no output and I would like to echo "connected" if it is infact connected because I have a few php files and I need to find which one is causing the problem

Comment: where did you called the connect() function

Comment: The connect() function is called in another php file which requires_once the php file I posted above

Comment: if you are using the class DB_connect in another file  you have to call the the function before using the this->conn

Answer (score 0):

You defined `$conn` as a `private` property of `DB_connect`: it can't be accessed outside of the `class`. Redefine it to be a `public` property and it'll work:

```
class DB_Connect {
   public $conn;

   public function connect() {

   }
}
```

**Example usage**

First create an instance of DB_Connect and then call $conn property.

```
$db = new DB_Connect();
$db->connect();

$link = $db->conn;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but at the moment the other file which uses this function is irrelevant. I'm running the php file(one I posted above) from the browser. All I want is some on screen output so I can see what's going on

Comment: Well, if you don't instantiate the class running the code won't help. I think you should look for some guides on OOP in php, then come back to SO and post your issue. @Colin

Comment: Oh ok I think my problem was trying to put the debug code in the wrong file. I'll put it in the file which instantiates the class. Thanks